How do I get Free Cash Flow data from Finviz on a Google Sheet?
I'm scraping data from Finviz for financial information such as P/E ratio, Debt/Equity ratio, etc., and I can't get free cash flow growth. My formula on google sheets for Currant Ratio for McDonald's, for instance looks like this:
=substitute(index(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx&t="&MCD&"&p=d","table",10),9,4),"*","")
and that data loads without a problem. I can't get free cash flow numbers though. I'm trying to get the FCF growth, and even getting the TTM free cash flow and the prior year number and it isn't showing up. I also can't find what the table index number is when I inspect on Chrome. Any help would be very helpful.

Using Index Sheet Function
Your sheet function is almost there, I corrected some strings in your sheet Formula.
From this:
=substitute(index(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx&t="&MCD&"&p=d","table",10),9,4),"*","")
To This:
=substitute(index(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashxt="&"MCD"&"&p=d","table",10),7,4),"*","")
I corrected the Value of your concatenation from "&MCD&"  to "&"MCD"&" to make the link work.
To get the desired output the table display below will help you navigate.
This is the step by step on how you get each data you want base on the function you've given.

To get the desired output you just need to navigate your parameters Row and Column




Row = 7
Column = 4

To get the desired data  a sample below is how you get the P/FCF you just need to adjust your row and column.
Sample function: =INDEX(url, 7, 4)
Reference:

Index


Thank you! I'm trying to get the free cash flow growth, so I need to get the table of the financial statements which is lower down on the page. All of the formulas that require from this table haven't been a problem, it's getting the numbers from the financial statements (the free cash flow rows or just the % change of free cash flow) that's the problem.

Did you mean this table? =IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&"MCD"&"&p=d","table",12)

Or this one =IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&"MCD"&"&p=d","table",15)

Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you.

Those analyst changes and insiders. The table I'm looking for is much further down the page. Thanks!
